# How to call subflow in FlowResponder

Tags: corda

I have problem about call flow under FlowResponder.

[Scenario explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPV1Y.jpg)

As you can see I need to call subflow for insert/update just only for NodeB.
Can I do that?

Here when I try I got this error

> java.io.IOException: Payload invalid
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImplKt.checkPayloadIs(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:605) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.receive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:231) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:44) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:48) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:74) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:24) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:212) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:197) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows.CustomerIssueFlowResponder.call(CustomerIssueFlow.kt:196) ~[classes/:?]
>    at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows.CustomerIssueFlowResponder.call(CustomerIssueFlow.kt:177) ~[classes/:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
>    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Described type with descriptor net.corda:Rd6hxg+0oJROxKDXK8OerA== was expected to be of type class net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction but was java.util.List
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:133) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:109) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api$default(DeserializationInput.kt:108) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:98) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:80) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
>    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImplKt.checkPayloadIs(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:603) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]

Here initiate flow code

```html
package th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.confidential.IdentitySyncFlow
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command
import net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireThat
import net.corda.core.flows.*
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker
import net.corda.core.utilities.unwrap
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.contracts.CustomerContract
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.core.commons.CordappConstants
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.dto.CustomerIssueData
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.services.CustomerService
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.states.Address
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.states.Consent
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.states.CustomerState
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.utils.CordappValidationUtils.Companion.requiredNotWhen
import java.util.*

@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class CustomerIssueFlow(private val customerIssueData: CustomerIssueData) : FlowLogic<String>() {

    companion object {
        object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Generating transaction based on new IOU.")
        object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
        object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Signing transaction with our private key.")
        object GATHERING_SIGS : ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
        }

        object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
        }

        fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                GATHERING_SIGS,
                FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        )
    }

    override val progressTracker = tracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): String {
        // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        // Stage 1.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
        // Generate an unsigned transaction.

        val customerService = serviceHub.cordaService(CustomerService::class.java)

        //#################################################################//
        val pahNode = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getPeerByLegalName(CordappConstants.Node.PAH) as Party
        val participants = listOf(ourIdentity, pahNode)

        val customerStateAndRef = customerService.findByIdCardNoAndPartner(idCarNo = customerIssueData.customerData.idCardNo!!, partner = customerIssueData.customerData.partner!!)

        //check duplicate customer
        requiredNotWhen(customerStateAndRef == null, "Customer already registered")

        val addresses = customerIssueData.customerData.addresses?.map { it ->
            Address(
                    seqId = it.seqId,
                    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    type = it.type,
                    houseNumber = it.houseNumber,
                    street = it.street,
                    subDistrict = it.subDistrict,
                    district = it.district,
                    province = it.province,
                    postalCode = it.postalCode,
                    countryCode = it.countryCode,
                    mobile = it.mobile,
                    telephone = it.telephone
            )
        }

        val consentsArray = customerIssueData.customerData.consents?.map { it ->
            Consent(
                    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    partner = it.partner,
                    product = it.product,
                    reference = it.reference,
                    createDate = it.createDate
            )
        }

        val linearId = UniqueIdentifier()

        val customerState = CustomerState(
                linearId = linearId,
                externalCustomerNo = customerIssueData.customerData.externalCustomerNo!!,
                title = customerIssueData.customerData.title!!,
                firstName = customerIssueData.customerData.firstName!!,
                middleName = customerIssueData.customerData.middleName!!,
                lastName = customerIssueData.customerData.lastName!!,
                idCardNo = customerIssueData.customerData.idCardNo!!,
                email = customerIssueData.customerData.email!!,
                partner = customerIssueData.customerData.partner!!,
                product = customerIssueData.customerData.product!!,
                consents = consentsArray,
                status = CordappConstants.CustomerStatus.Active,
                addresses = addresses,
                participants = participants,
                createDate = Date(),
                createBy = customerIssueData.customerData.username!!,
                changeDate = Date(),
                changeBy = customerIssueData.customerData.username!!
        )

        val txCommand = Command(CustomerContract.Commands.Issue(), customerState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(customerState, CustomerContract.CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(txCommand)

        //#################################################################//
        // Stage 2.
        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
        // Verify that the transaction is valid.
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Stage 3.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        // Sign the transaction.
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // Stage 4.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
        val session = (customerState.participants - ourIdentity).map { initiateFlow(it) }
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, session, GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

        // Stage 5.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.

        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
        return customerState.linearId.toString()
    }

}

@InitiatedBy(CustomerIssueFlow::class)
class CustomerIssueFlowResponder(val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {// TwoPartyDealFlow.Acceptor(otherSideSession) {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        // val finalTx = super.call()
        println("######## START CustomerIssueFlowResponder ########################################################")
        println(ourIdentity)
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherSideSession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                // val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                //"This must be an CustomerState." using (output is CustomerState)
            }
        }

        val stx = subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherSideSession, checkSufficientSignatures = false))
        val customerState = stx.tx.outputs.single().data as CustomerState
        subFlow(CustomerPAHIssueOrUpdateFlow(customerState))
        println("######## END CustomerIssueFlowResponder ########################################################")

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)


    }
}
```

And subflow

```html
package th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command
import net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireThat
import net.corda.core.flows.*
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker
import net.corda.core.utilities.loggerFor
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.contracts.CustomerContract
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.core.commons.CordappConstants
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.services.CustomerService
import th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.states.CustomerState

@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByService
@StartableByRPC
class CustomerPAHIssueOrUpdateFlow(private val customerState: CustomerState) : FlowLogic<String>() {

    companion object {
        val log = loggerFor<CustomerPAHIssueOrUpdateFlow>()

        object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Generating transaction based on new IOU.")
        object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
        object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Signing transaction with our private key.")
        object GATHERING_SIGS : ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
        }

        object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
        }

        fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                GATHERING_SIGS,
                FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        )
    }

    override val progressTracker = tracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): String {
        // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        // Stage 1.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
        // Generate an unsigned transaction.

        val customerService = serviceHub.cordaService(CustomerService::class.java)

        //#################################################################//
        val pahNode = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getPeerByLegalName(CordappConstants.Node.PAH) as Party
        //val participants = listOf(ourIdentity, pahNode)

        val customerStateAndRef = customerService.findByIdCardNoAndPartner(idCarNo = customerState.idCardNo!!, partner = CordappConstants.PartnerNameList.PAH)

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
        if (customerStateAndRef == null) {
            log.info("===================================================")
            val linearId = UniqueIdentifier()
            val customerOutputState = customerState.copy(linearId = linearId, participants = listOf(pahNode), partner = CordappConstants.PartnerNameList.PAH)
            val txCommand = Command(CustomerContract.Commands.Issue(), customerState.participants.map { it.owningKey })

            log.info("Create new JVC Customer : {}", customerOutputState)

            txBuilder.addOutputState(customerOutputState, CustomerContract.CONTRACT_ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand)
            log.info("===================================================")
        } else {
            log.info("===================================================")
            val txCommand = Command(CustomerContract.Commands.Update(), customerState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
            val customerOutputState = customerState.copy(participants = listOf(pahNode), partner = CordappConstants.PartnerNameList.PAH)

            log.info("Update existing JVC Customer : {}", customerOutputState)

            txBuilder.addInputState(customerStateAndRef)
            txBuilder.addOutputState(customerOutputState, CustomerContract.CONTRACT_ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand)
            log.info("===================================================")
        }

        //#################################################################//
        // Stage 2.
        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
        // Verify that the transaction is valid.
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Stage 3.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        // Sign the transaction.
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // Stage 4.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
        val session = (customerState.participants - ourIdentity).map { initiateFlow(it) }
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, session, GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

        // Stage 5.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.

        /*For syndicate loan phase
        //Initial default wallet with 0.00 THB
        subFlow(WalletIssueFlow(WalletIssueData(
                amount = BigDecimal.ZERO,
                currency = DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
                customerId = linearId.id.toString()
                )))
        */

        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
        return customerState.linearId.toString()
    }

}

@InitiatedBy(CustomerPAHIssueOrUpdateFlow::class)
class CustomerPAHIssueOrUpdateFlowResponder(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                //val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
               // "This must be an CustomerState." using (output is CustomerState)
            }
        }

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not related to calling a subflow from a flow. Instead, the issue is in this line in `CustomerIssueFlowResponder`:

```
val stx = subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherSideSession, checkSufficientSignatures = false))
```

There is no corresponding send of a transaction from the other side of the flow, causing an exception of the type:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: Described type with descriptor
>   net.corda:Rd6hxg+0oJROxKDXK8OerA== was expected to be of type class
>   net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction but was java.util.List

Instead of calling `ReceiveTransactionFlow`, just use the transaction returned by `SignTransactionFlow`.

Comment: Thanks Joel that's work fine, so next that I must concern is about control exception for each flow.