# Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", corda

Tags: corda

This is the error I run into when I run my corda initiator flow.

```
amqp.DeserializationInput. - Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", 
type="net.corda.core.contracts.Amount", msg="Described type with descriptor 
net.corda:7mttgXO2HdBLwATyV7pCpg== was expected to be of type class 
net.corda.core.contracts.Amount but was class net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction
```

When I check the initiator node log, it says, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Payload invalid

Corda version that I use is 4.4.
Tokens version: 1.2.
Accounts version: 1.0.2

When ran, without creating accounts, No such errors were thrown.

Initiator Flow:

```
public class InitiateTicketMovementFlow extends FlowLogic<String> {
    private final String buyer;
    private final String issuer;
    private final StateRef assetReference;

public InitiateTicketMovementFlow(String buyer, String issuer, String hash, int index) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
    this.issuer = issuer;
    this.assetReference = new StateRef(SecureHash.parse(hash), index);
}

@Override
@Suspendable
public String call() throws FlowException {

    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

    AccountInfo issuerAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this)
            .accountInfo(issuer).get(0).getState().getData();

    AnonymousParty issuerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(issuerAccountInfo));

    AccountInfo receiverAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this)
            .accountInfo(buyer).get(0).getState().getData();

    AnonymousParty buyerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(receiverAccountInfo));

    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria()
            .withStateRefs(ImmutableList.of(assetReference));

    StateAndRef<CustomTicket> ticketStateStateAndRef = getServiceHub().getVaultService()
            .queryBy(CustomTicket.class, queryCriteria).getStates().get(0);

    CustomTicket ticketState = ticketStateStateAndRef.getState().getData();

    TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);

    MoveTokensUtilities.addMoveNonFungibleTokens(txBuilder, getServiceHub(),
            ticketState.toPointer(CustomTicket.class), receiverAccountInfo.getHost());

    FlowSession buyerSession = initiateFlow(receiverAccountInfo.getHost());
            buyerSession.send(ticketState.getValuation());

    List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>> inputs = subFlow(new ReceiveStateAndRefFlow<>(buyerSession));
    
    List<FungibleToken> moneyReceived = buyerSession.receive(List.class).unwrap(value -> value);

    MoveTokensUtilities.addMoveTokens(txBuilder, inputs, moneyReceived);

    SignedTransaction selfSignedTransaction = getServiceHub()
            .signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, ImmutableList.of(issuerAccountInfo.getHost().getOwningKey()));

    SignedTransaction signedTransaction = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
            selfSignedTransaction, ImmutableList.of(buyerSession, initiateFlow(issuerAccountInfo.getHost())), Collections.singleton(issuerAccountInfo.getHost().getOwningKey())));

    SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new FinalityFlow(
            signedTransaction, ImmutableList.of(buyerSession)));
    subFlow(new UpdateDistributionListFlow(stx));

    return "\nTicket is sold to "+ buyer;
    }
}
```

ReceiverFlow:

```
public class ResponderTicketFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
private final FlowSession otherPartySession;

public ResponderTicketFlow(FlowSession otherPartySession) {
    this.otherPartySession = otherPartySession;
}

@Override
@Suspendable
public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {

    Amount<Currency> price =  otherPartySession.receive(Amount.class).unwrap(amount -> amount);

    Amount<TokenType> priceToken = new Amount<>(price.getQuantity(),
            FiatCurrency.Companion.getInstance(price.getToken().getCurrencyCode()));

    PartyAndAmount<TokenType> partyAndAmount = new PartyAndAmount<>(otherPartySession.getCounterparty(), priceToken);

    Selector selector = new DatabaseTokenSelection(getServiceHub());

    Pair<List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>>, List<FungibleToken>> inputsAndOutputs = selector
                    .generateMove(Collections.singletonList(new Pair<>(otherPartySession.getCounterparty(), priceToken)), getOurIdentity());

    subFlow(new SendStateAndRefFlow(otherPartySession, inputsAndOutputs.getFirst()));
    otherPartySession.send(inputsAndOutputs.getSecond());

    subFlow(new SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession) {
        @Override
        protected void checkTransaction(@NotNull SignedTransaction stx) throws FlowException {
            // Custom Logic to validate transaction.
        }
    });
    return subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession));
   }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: In the logs you should see what is the flow that is complaining, you only reported the error message here. Check out this other answser to an issue that looks the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195261/how-to-call-subflow-in-flowresponder .

Answer (score 0):

As Alessandro said, I'd check out that other stackoverflow question as there might be a clue what's going wrong with your app.

Another thing to be aware of that can cause serialization issues is when you don't have the @CordaSerializable directive on classes that you've added to a Corda state.

So if your state uses a custom java class, OR you don't have the right marker on your classes, it can cause issues when corda tries to unpack your objects. Note the 'ConstructorForDeserialization' in this corda state.

For example:

```
@ConstructorForDeserialization
private IOUState(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower, Amount<Currency> paid, UniqueIdentifier linearId){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.lender = lender;
    this.borrower = borrower;
    this.paid = paid;
    this.linearId = linearId;
}
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/obligation/states/IOUState.java#L34